# zxing is generating a QR code instead of a Bar Code

Tags: android, zxing

I am using zxing 2.0.
I'm trying to create a Bar code, but instead it's creating a QR code.
Here's what I'm using:

```
Context context = getActivity();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, EncodeActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intents.Encode.ACTION);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.TYPE, Contents.Type.TEXT);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA, "12345678901"); 
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.FORMAT, BarcodeFormat.UPC_A);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.FORMAT, BarcodeFormat.UPC_A);
```

and all the other `intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.*`

try

```
Context context = getActivity();
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", Text);
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", "12345678901");
    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "UPC_A");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.
I was able to remove the setAction also.

Comment: Btw trytryagain, this was extremely helpful. Is there some way I can get you more points? I clicked on the green check icon.

Comment: @TryTryAgain, hi I wonder, how do u derive "ENCODE_TYPE" or "ENCODE_DATA" please? Because I didn't find getInt() for those in ZXing's Encode Package. Thank you :)

Comment: @ThetMonAye you should ask a new question with the problem you are having.

Comment: @TryTryAgain, I realized that I cant ask question anymore... cos I got too many down votes :( but anyway I will be appreciate if you can answer though.

Comment: @ThetMonAye unfortunately, I'm not even sure how to help...And we are not allowed to carry on conversation/diagnosing/troubleshooting in comments, sorry. Good luck... http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents & http://code.google.com/p/zxing/w/list Also, mentioning your question ban on meta.stackoverflow.com may be helpful. I don't see anything that shows too much downvoting on you or anything else you shouldn't be able to get help with: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers